# Space of $f(0)=f(1)$: Is Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, inner-products

Let $S$ be space consisting of collection of square integrable continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the constraint $f(0)=f(1)$. So $S$ is an inner product space with the inner product $$\langle f,g \rangle =\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx.$$

Now the question is whether $S$ is a Hilbert space or not??

Now, $S$ to be a Hilbert space it is necessary to show that $S$ is complete metric space with respect to its natural metric 
$$\|f-g\|=\sqrt{\langle f-g,f-g\rangle}.$$  To show completeness I need to show that every Cauchy sequence in that space is convergent.

Here I stuck. Specifically I have no idea how to show the sequence of $f$ has limit $f_0$ which has the property that $f_0(0)=f_0(1)$.

Is there any counter example to show that $S$ is not a Hilbert space?  Thanks for any suggestion.

**Added later:** Thanks to @Aweygan for pointing out the role of the (previous) restriction of positivity to the function. Though primarily I was interested about positive valued function, with out loss of generality I am now considering the mean shift version of the functions which enable the new functions to take values in real line. I modified this point in the edited question.

Comment: It is not even a vector space, as it is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Aweygan I can not see why it is not closed under scalar multiplication. Could you explain ?

Comment: The OP requires functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^+$. For any such function $f\in S$ and any real number $a<0$, $af\notin S$

Comment: Ok, I have missed the $+$. By the way I believe there would also have been a problem with completeness, the constraint is not enough to prevent continuous functions converging to non-continuous ones.

Comment: There is no square root.

Comment: @nicomezi. Sorry it was a typo. Square root should not be there. I corrected it.

Comment: @Aweygan. The application which I am dealing with, this non-positivity part can be relaxed by considering the the centered function(pointwise mean) which can take any value in real line and its space $S^*$. Then also the question is whether $S^*$ is a Hilbert sapce or not?

Comment: @Janak: Indeed, the space of all positive-values functions is not a vector space. Indeed, it is not even a group under addition, as the additive inverse is missing. Indeed, assuming $0\notin\mathbb R^+$ (that's how I'd interpret that notation), it is not even a monoid, as the neutral element is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding convergence and completeness: For $n\in N$ let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\leq 1/2-1/(n+2)$ and $f_n(x)=1$ for $x\geq 1/2.$  Let $f_n(x)$ be linear for $x\in [1/2-1/(n+2),1/2].$

Then $(f_n)_{n\in N}$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the norm $\|f-g\|=[\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|^2\;dx]^{1/2}.$

Let $h(x)=0$ for $x\leq 1/2$ and $h(x)=1$ for $x>1/2.$ The function $h$ is not continuous. And it has the property that  for any continuous $g:[0,1]\to R$  there exists $r>0$ and here exist $a,b$ with either $0<a<b<1/2$ or $1/2<a<b<1$, such that $x\in [a,b]\implies |g(x)-h(x)|\geq r.$

But for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $x\in [a,b]\implies f_n(x)=h(x).$  So $\lim \sup \|g-f_n\|^2\geq \int_a^b |g(x)-h(x)|^2\;dx\geq (b-a)r^2>0.$  So $(f_n)_{n\in N}$ cannot converge in norm to any continuous $g.$

Comment: My assumption was $f_n$ are continuous functions. In your example $f_n$ function is "not" continuous having discontinuity at two points (1/2-1/(n+2) and 1/2).

Comment: @Janak In fact, the function $f_n$ is continuous. Images psoted in answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97171/cauchy-sequence-in-x-on-0-1-with-norm-int-01-xtdt) might help you visualize the sequence $f_n$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you. I got the point.

Comment: Could you please suggest me further: Is it possible to make this space($S$) a  Hilbert space by imposing minimal conditions on $f$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A Hilbert-space norm must by def'n give a a complete metric.  I don't think that any  infinite-dimensional  subspace of $S$ can be a complete metric space with this norm, but I haven't proved it. But I think it shouldn't be hard to do so.