# The sequence of piecewise linear functions converges to a piecewise constant function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The sequence of continuous functions$$f_n(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
     -1 & x\in [0, 1/2 - 1/n] \\[6pt]
     n(x - 1/2) & x\in [1/2 - 1/n, 1/2 +1/n] \\[6pt]
  1 & x\in [1/2 +1/n, 1]
   \end{cases}$$

Converges to the function.
$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
     -1 & x\in [0, 1/2 ) \\[6pt]
     0 & x = 1/2 \\[6pt]
  1 & x\in (1/2 , 1]
   \end{cases} $$

My question is that How can we get $f$? How this sequence of functions converges to $f$?
How it comes $0$. Please explain me, I am not getting this.

Comment: Please define $f_n(x)$ explicitly.

Comment: So, the limit of a function is usually a function, but in this case, the only domain for the limit function is the single point $\frac12$. Is this the problem exactly as it was presented to you?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sir Exact Problem is this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152233/showing-c0-1-d-1-is-not-a-complete-metric-space

Comment: If the $f_n$ are the same as in that problem, the the limit is not $0$, except at $x=1/2$, where it is obviously zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sir would you like to explain that How we calculate that $f$? I am totally confused.

Comment: Since you haven't asked a clear question, I have no doubt you are confused. You asked why it is zero, and I note it is not zero. You ask about $f$, but there is no $f$ in your question. What are you really trying to understand?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews wait a minute Sir I am editing the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Now see.

Comment: People do some incredibly weird things with MathJax code on this site, but this is the first time I've seen \text{} with nothing inside the \text{} except math notation enclosed in dollar signs.  You could have just written the mathematical notation.  \text{} has a purpose, and that is certainly not its purpose.  I changed it. (Also, I replaced "array" with "cases".) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get f (you go point by point). you watch both how is $f_n$ defined and where, when $n\rightarrow\infty$ interval $[0,1/2-1/n]\rightarrow [0,1/2)$ , so your limit function f is equal to -1 on $[0,1/2)$ . now for the second case $[1/2-1/n,1/2+1/n]\rightarrow \{1/2\}$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$,this is single point and $f(1/2)=n\cdot 0 =0$ now for the last case $[1/2+1/n,1]\rightarrow (1/2,1]$ and $f=1$, that all .